# ng-repeat and databinding in not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angularjs and trying to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="size in sizes">
    {{size.name}} 
    <input  ng-model="price_{{size.id}}" required type="number">
</div>
```

I have read about how `ng-repeat` and data binding works. but can't understand how to solve such problem, My product may have many sizes and I want  to display so many input boxes as the number of sizes. So that I can enter a price for each size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to specify a price per size, why not assign the price to a property of size?

```
<input ng-model="size.price" type="number" required>
```

Otherwise you can define prices as an object in your controller:

```
$scope.prices = {};
```

And create a property per id:

```
<input ng-model="prices[size.id]" type="number" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concating variables with `_` in the model, use data structure. For example declare `price` as an object,which properties are ids of sizes.In that case you can write:

```
<input  ng-model="price[size.id]" required type="number">
```

Or declare `price` as an array, and use `$index` instead of `size.id`,if it's not so important:

```
<input  ng-model="price[$index]" required type="number">
```